# Should I add an article in the following sentence?

Tags: articles

If I want to ask generally about differences of an organ, should I add an article before the name of the organ?

For example:

> What are the differences between large intestine and small intestine

I saw this question on Facebook and I am not sure if it's correct or not. If it's correct then I don't understand why there should not have an articles before the names of the organs. (a small intestine and a large intestine)

Answer (score 3):

As far as this sentence goes, I would include the article "the", because you are specifically talking about ***the* large intestine** and ***the* small intestine**.  So it would be this:

> What are the differences between **the** large intestine and **the** small intestine?

Another way you could put it is to say:

> What are the differences between large **intestines** and small **intestines**?

This also works for being general.  You wouldn't say "the large intestines" however, because for each person, there's only one large intestine.